# prove that if a function is differentiable then other function is constant

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I got this exercise:

Let $\sigma:R\rightarrow R$ be continuous function. And let:

$f(x,y) = x\sigma(\frac{y}{x})$  if $x \ne 0$

$f(x,y) = 0$  if $x = 0$

Prove that if $f$ is differentiable in $(0,0)$ then $\sigma$ is constant.

I tried to find the partial derivatives and use the definition of differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: look at the directional derivative along the line $y=mx$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ is differentiable. By definition of derivative there exist $a,b$ such that $\frac {f(x,y)-ax-by} {\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}}} \to 0$ as $x^{2}+y^{2} \to 0$. Replace $y$ by $xy$ and conclude that the limit as $x \to 0$ from the right equals the limit as $x \to 0$ from the left for fixed $y$  only if $\sigma (y)=a+by$. Now continuity of $f$  implies $b=0$ so $\sigma $ is a constant.

Comment: Hi, thanks, can you give a hint for the ability to change y with xy ?

Comment: If $h(x,y) \to 0$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ then $h(x,xy)$ also tends to $0$ [because $(x,xy) \to (0,0)$]. Hence it is legitimate to replace $y$ by $xy$.

Comment: I think $b=0$ can be also concluded from $b = f_y(0,y) = 0$ (the partial derivative by y when x= 0)

Comment: @dafnahaktana I am not using difefrentiability in this last step. I am using continuity. Once we prove that $\sigma(y)=a+by$ we get $f(x,y)=ax+by$ for $x \neq 0$ and $0$ for $x=0$. So $ax+by$ must tend to $0$ as $x \to 0$ for any $y$. This means $by=0$ for all $y$, so $b=0$.